# SSAS Tabular calculated measures missing from Power View fields list

Tags: sql-server, ssas, pivot-table, tabular, powerview

I have defined a calculated measure named "Gross Margin" for my "FactInvoiceLineItem" table. I can see this measure in the Measures dimension (along with several others):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJSj6.png]

These measures work fine in a PivotTable, but they are absent from the field list in Power View:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZvjZ.png]

I've seen similar issues with PowerPivot and e.g. date columns but that issue shouldn't apply here since the result of the calculation is numeric. We've tried wrapping the calculation in a CALCULATE() anyway, but it didn't help.

There are examples of using measures with Power View from a PowerPivot model. Am I missing some setting in my model, or is this a quirk with Power View and SSAS Tabular?

Comment: I don't think it's a quirk with SSAS Tabular and Power View.  I have used them together on multiple projects and have not experienced this issue.  Can you confirm the calculation and source fields used are numeric? Have you tried deleting and re-adding the measure? Also, try scripting out the model in XMLA and look at hte definition to see what it says for that measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mmarie suggests, it's not a limitation of Power View and Tabular - except that Power View only supports numeric measures.

We had included in our calculated measure some custom formatting using FORMAT() to apply parenthesis to negative numbers, which rendered our nice numeric calculation into text. Thus, Power View wouldn't display our measures because they were no longer numeric!

Stripping the FORMAT() out returned the calculation to a numeric type, and made it available in Power View.